# NoClassDefFoundError encountered while fixing CRLF sequence in HttpHeader

Tags: cookies, http-headers, noclassdeffounderror, esapi, veracode

After performing Vera code scan on my code, a flaw was reported saying " Improper Neutralization of CRLF Sequences in HTTP Headers ('HTTP Response Splitting - CWE ID 113') on the below code.

```
public void writeCookies() {
            for (final Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                super.addCookie(cookie);
            }
```

The flaw code reported is super.addCookie(cookie). To fix this I added below code

```
public void writeCookies() {
            for (final Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                cookie.setSecure(true);
                ESAPI.httpUtilities().addCookie(((HttpServletResponse)super.getResponse()),cookie);
            }
        }
```

Now the Veracode scan doesn't report any flaw in the code. However, while running the application, I get NoClassDefFoundError as below

> Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory Error Code: 500 Target
>   Servlet: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor
>   Error Stack:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory 
>        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method) 
>        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94) 
>        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:171) 
>        at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method) 
>        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:180) 
>        at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:74) 
>        at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.httpUtilities(ESAPI.java:121)

My ESAPI.properties file is at location src/main/resources/ESAPI.properties
The content of ESAPI.properties file is

*

> Encoder.AllowMultipleEncoding=false Encoder.AllowMixedEncoding=false
>   Encoder.DefaultCodecList=HTMLEntityCodec,PercentCodec,JavaScriptCodec
>   ESAPI.HTTPUtilities=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultHTTPUtilities

*

Please suggest me on how to fix this NoClassDefFoundError...

Comment: It's in your stacktrace.  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory`

That library is not on your classpath.  What version of ESAPI are you using?

Comment: I'm using ESAPI 2.1.0.1. I suspect there is some configuration issue with configuring ESAPI httputilities, I'm not sure the above properties set in ESAPI.properties is the right way to set for httputilities.

Comment: What happens when you add this to your application:  `<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
`