# NoClassDefFoundError encountered while fixing CRLF sequence in HttpHeader

Tags: http, security, cookies, owasp, esapi

After performing Vera code scan on my code, a flaw was reported saying " Improper Neutralization of CRLF Sequences in HTTP Headers ('HTTP Response Splitting - CWE ID 113') on the below code.

```
public void writeCookies() {
            for (final Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                super.addCookie(cookie);
            }
```

The flaw code reported is super.addCookie(cookie). To fix this I added below code

```
public void writeCookies() {
            for (final Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                cookie.setSecure(true);
                ESAPI.httpUtilities().addCookie(((HttpServletResponse)super.getResponse()),cookie);
            }
        }
```

Now the Veracode scan doesn't report any flaw in the code. However, while running the application, I get NoClassDefFoundError as below

> Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory Error Code: 500 Target
>   Servlet: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor
>   Error Stack: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94) at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:171) at
>   java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:180) at
>   org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:74) at
>   org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.httpUtilities(ESAPI.java:121)

My ESAPI.properties file is at location src/main/resources/ESAPI.properties The content of ESAPI.properties file is

> Encoder.AllowMultipleEncoding=false Encoder.AllowMixedEncoding=false
>   Encoder.DefaultCodecList=HTMLEntityCodec,PercentCodec,JavaScriptCodec
>   ESAPI.HTTPUtilities=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultHTTPUtilities

Please suggest me on how to fix this NoClassDefFoundError. I'm using ESAPI 2.1.0.1. I suspect there is some configuration issue with configuring ESAPI httputilities, I'm not sure the above properties set in ESAPI.properties is the right way to set for httputilities.

Comment: check that missing depedency with: mvn dependency:tree

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NoClassDefFoundError encountered while fixing CRLF sequence in HttpHeader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261616/noclassdeffounderror-encountered-while-fixing-crlf-sequence-in-httpheader)